# How do I get the Furries into the cages?

Tags: saints-row-iv

In the DLC quest "Enter The Dominatrix" there is a part where Dom wants you to put his "pets" back in their cages. The club is full of Furries running around, but I don't see how I am supposed to get them in the cages hanging from the roof.

I tried clubbing them, they appear to be unkillable, so I had hoped they would run to the cages if I beat them, but they don't. Do I need to hit them and hope I knock them in the air, and hope they fly into the cages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to use Telekinesis to pick the Furries up and then throw them into the cage.

This didn't occur to me before because I didn't have telekinesis unlocked when I did the DLC, so I didn't know how it worked.

Comment: i managed to put one in cage by kicking it repeatedly :)